# Multiple class selecting in CSS

Tags: css

```
.upload header {...}
```

Styling will be applied to any header that is a child of any element with class of '.upload'.

Is it possible to do this?

```
.upload header, form {...}
```

Or will I have to specify the class for every *type selector* ?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: More informations about your questions pls.., it is possible to use commas,  but i am not sure is that what you wanna know? because that css would select every header as child of upload AND only every form BUT NOT! form as child of upload, only form alone because of comma!

Comment: Then your `css` will be applied to `header` and `form` tag. In `header` only if it has a parent element with `.upload` class

Comment: So I would have to do .upload header, .upload form {...} I'm planning on wrapping html with div with class of upload. I have other css that conflicts so I'm trying to seperate

Comment: right! .upload header, .upload form {...} would work

Comment: Please take a few minutes to explain and clarify your problem, remember we have none of your knowledge about what you're doing, or what you're trying to do. Or why you're doing it. It may help to read the "*[mcve]*" and "*[ask]*" guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that. The comma for selector works like the following:

```
div > nav,
p {
   display: block; 
}
```

Is exactly the same as writting

```
div > nav { display: block; }
p { display: block; }
```

The comma is used to re-use rules, but each selector is global, and does not use the same parent.

In your case, if you want to make the rule only apply to those `form` elements that are children of `.upload`, you would have to do

```
.upload header, .upload form {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with two selectors. First set your styles with * and then reset the same styles if you only want it to be applied to the first child element.

```
.upload *:first-child {
    background: blue;
}

.upload *:first-child *:first-child {
    background: none;
}
```